# Is a finite function bounded on a closed bounded set?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Given a finite function $f$ in $\boldsymbol{R}^n$, if set $A$ is a closed bounded set, could I say $\{f(\boldsymbol{x}), \boldsymbol{x} \in A\}$ is bounded?

The definition of finite function is $-\infty < f(\boldsymbol{x}) < +\infty, \forall \boldsymbol{x} \in \boldsymbol{R}^n$.

Comment: What is a finite function?

Comment: The finite function is described in this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146136/what-does-it-mean-when-a-function-is-finite)

Comment: It should be part of **your** question.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=\frac 1 x$ for $0<x\leq 1$ and $f(0)=0$ is a counterexample. I am taking $n=1$.

Comment: thank you, but could I add some conditions to make the function bounded?

Comment: Continuity should be enough if by finite you mean bounded.

Comment: @Ze-NanLi Continuity and monotonicity are both sufficient in the case $n=1$. Monotonicity in each variable would be fine for $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Comment: I know continuity is enough, but maybe this condition is too strict?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, thanks, but i also want to know, if the function is lower semi-continuous and convex? could it be bounded?

Comment: @Ravi You seem to know what a finite function is! Would be good if you can shed light on the topic for us!

Comment: I think OP is saying finite function for a real valued function as opposed to an extended real valued function. It is not uncommon for people to use the term 'finite valued'.